# assignment to a dereferenced unique_ptr

Tags: c++11

I've looked through other questions about std::unique_ptr but have been unable to find a clear and concise answer to this question.

Given the following code:

```
std::unique_ptr<someClass> a(new someClass);
someClass b;
*a = b;
```

has the heap-allocated someClass in the first line been leaked? Does it get garbage collected?

I'd appreciate an explanation of what exactly is occurring in this code wrt memory allocation.

Comment: You're not actually changing the pointer here, only the value it's pointing to. So no, nothing is leaked.

Comment: To help understand what people are saying here, imagine that `someClass` is actually an `int`. Does overwriting `2` with `3` leak any memory? Of course not, it's just that the old memory has been overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `unique_ptr` can only leak if *you* [`release`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release) the owned resource and don't destroy it yourself.

In your case, the [`operator*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator*) of `unique_ptr` is called for `a` and returns an lvalue referring to the pointee. You then call the copy assignment operator for that pointee, but that does not in any way affect the management of the memory it occupies.
The memory for the heap object is released at the end of the scope that `a` was defined in.

Comment: In light of this I think I need to revise my question to make it a little more basic. What actually happens to the new'd someClass?

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus To the nude `someClass`? Well... ;)

Comment: @Nicolas: It's still there. The only difference is the assignment operator has been called on it, so its internal state is (probably) different.

Comment: @Columbo so would the sample code in the question be a 'correct' way of changing the value referred to by a unique_ptr?

Answer (score -2):

EDIT is WRONG Unique_ptrs does not have reference counters.

Your unique_ptr will be destroyed only if the internal counter that smartpointers have is 0. In that case is still 1.

Comment: Since when do `unique_ptr`s have internal counters?

Comment: all the smart pointers in C++ have an internal counter that points how many references have. When this pointer is 0 that pointer is destroyed automatically.  "The simplest garbage collection scheme is reference counting or reference linking" http://ootips.org/yonat/4dev/smart-pointers.html

Comment: Not all smart pointers use reference counting. `unique_ptr` certainly doesn't.

Comment: Oh I thought that all smartpointer used reference counting in their implementation. Sorry about my mistake.